# Create numerical discrete values if values in a column equal in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have a column of IDs in a dataframe that sometimes has duplicates, take for example,

| ID |
| --- |
| 209 |
| 315 |
| 109 |
| 315 |
| 451 |
| 209 |

What I want to do is take this column and create another column that indicates what ID the row belongs to. i.e. I want it to look like,

| ID | ID Category |
| --- | --- |
| 209 | 1 |
| 315 | 2 |
| 109 | 3 |
| 315 | 2 |
| 451 | 4 |
| 209 | 1 |

Essentially, I want to loop through the IDs and if it equals to a previous one, I indicate that it is from the same ID, and if it is a new ID, I create a new indicator for it.

Does anyone know is there a quick function in R that I could do this with? Or have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to factor with levels ordered with `unique` (order of appearance in the data set) and then to numeric:

```r
data$IDCategory <- as.numeric(factor(data$ID, levels = unique(data$ID)))

#> data
#   ID IDCategory
#1 209          1
#2 315          2
#3 109          3
#4 315          2
#5 451          4
#6 209          1
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(ID= c(209,315,109,315,451,209))

data %>%
  left_join(
    data %>%
      distinct(ID) %>%
      mutate(`ID Category` = row_number())
  )
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>      ID `ID Category`
#>   <dbl>         <int>
#> 1   209             1
#> 2   315             2
#> 3   109             3
#> 4   315             2
#> 5   451             4
#> 6   209             1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(`ID Category` = as.numeric(interaction(ID, drop=TRUE)))
```

Answer with data.table

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)

df <- df[
  j = `ID Category` := as.numeric(interaction(ID, drop=TRUE))
]
```

The pro of this solution is that you can create an unique ID for a group of variables. Here you only need `ID`, but if you want to have an unique ID let say for the couple [`ID`—`Location`] you could.

```
data <- tibble(ID= c(209,209,209,315,315,315), Location = c("A","B","C","A","A","B"))
data <- data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(`ID Category` = as.numeric(interaction(ID, Location, drop=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
merge(data,
  data.frame(ID = unique(data$ID),
             ID.Category = seq_along(unique(data$ID))
  ), sort = F)
  
# ID ID.Category
# 1 209           1
# 2 209           1
# 3 315           2
# 4 315           2
# 5 109           3
# 6 451           4
```

data:

```
tibble(ID = c(209,315,109,315,451,209)) -> data
```